# Array of parametrized elements in VHDL

Tags: arrays, range, vhdl

In VHDL it is possible to create array type of parametrizable range in the way:

`type t_array_type is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)`

Now, is it possible to create an array of parametrizable elements? I.e. to have an array type where, while instantiating a signal, it is possible to define a range of `std_logic_vector`? Purpose of that is not having to declare separate array types for every `std_logic_vector` range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it. Declare type as:

`type t_array_type is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector;`

and then instantiate as:

`signal t_array_type(23 downto 0)(7 downto 0);`

Comment: This only works in VHDL-2008, though. In previous versions of VHDL, you are only allowed one unconstrained dimension and that must be the outside dimension - the one immediately following the keyword `type`.